# Resolve SAS macro variables

Tags: code-golf, parsing, interpreter

The [SAS programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_language) is a clunky, archaic language dating back to 1966 that's still in use today. The original compiler was written in [PL/I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I), and indeed much of the syntax derives from PL/I. SAS also has a preprocessor macro language which derives from [that of PL/I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I_preprocessor) as well. In this challenge, you'll be interpreting some simple elements of the SAS macro language.

In the SAS macro language, macro variables are defined using the `%let` keyword and printing to the log is done with `%put`. Statements end with semicolons. Here are some examples:

```
%let x = 5;
%let cool_beans =Cool beans;
%let what123=46.lel"{)-++;
```

Macro variable names are case insensitive and always match the regular expression `/[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*/i`. For the purposes of this challenge, we'll say the following:

- Macro variables can only hold values consisting entirely of printable ASCII characters *except* `;`, `&`, and `%`
- There will be no leading or trailing spaces in the values
- The values will never be more than 255 characters long
- Values may be empty
- Brackets and quotes in the values may be unmatched
- There can be any amount of space before and after the `=` in the `%let` statement and this space should be ignored
- There can be any amount of space before the terminal `;` in the `%let` statement and this space should similarly be ignored

When a macro variable is called, we say it "resolves" to its value. Macro variables are resolved by prepending `&`. There is an *optional* trailing `.` that denotes the end of the identifier. For example,

```
%put The value of x is &X..;
```

writes `The value of x is 5.` to the log. Note that two periods are required because a single period will be consumed by `&X.` and resolve to `5`. Also note that even though we defined `x` in lowercase, `&X` is the same as `&x` because macro variable names are case insensitive.

Here's where it gets tricky. Multiple `&`s can be strung together to resolve variables, and `&`s at the same level of nesting resolve at the same time. For example,

```
%let i = 1;
%let coolbeans1 = broseph;
%let broseph = 5;

%put &&coolbeans&i;  /* Prints broseph */
%put &&&coolbeans&i; /* Prints 5 */
```

The innermost `&`s resolve first, and resolution continues outward. Variable name matching is done greedily. In the second `%put` statement, the processor makes the following steps:

1. `&i` resolves to `1`, and the innermost leading `&` is consumed, giving us `&&coolbeans1`
2. `&coolbeans1` resolves to `broseph`, giving us `&broseph`
3. `&broseph` resolves to `5`.

If there are trailing `.`s, only a single `.` is consumed in resolution, even if there are multiple `&`s.

#### Task

Given between 1 and 10 `%let` statements separated by newlines and a single `%put` statement, print or return the result of the `%put` statement. Input can be accepted in any standard way.

You can assume that the input will always be valid and that the `%let` statements will preceed the `%put` statement. Variables that are defined will not be redefined in later `%let` statements.

If actually run in SAS, there would be no issues with variables resolving to variables that don't exist and everything will be syntactically correct as described above.

#### Examples

1. Input:

   ```
   %let dude=stuff;
   %let stuff=bEaNs;
   %put &&dude..;
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   bEaNs.
   ```
2. Input:

   ```
   %let __6 = 6__;
   %put __6&__6;
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   __66__
   ```
3. Input:

   ```
   %let i=1;
   %let hOt1Dog = BUNS;
   %put &&HoT&i.Dog are FUNS&i!");
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   BUNS are FUNS1!")
   ```
4. Input:

   ```
   %let x = {*':TT7d;
   %put SAS is weird.;
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   SAS is weird.
   ```
5. Input:

   ```
   %let var1   =  Hm?;
   %let var11 = var1;
   %let UNUSED = ;
   %put &&var11.....;
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Hm?....
   ```

   Note that `&&var11` matches `var11` since name matching is greedy. If there had been a `.`, i.e. `&&var1.1`, then `var1` would be matched and the extra 1 wouldn't be part of any name.

This is code golf, so the shortest solution in bytes wins!

Comment: How does the output from test case 1 have a period? Shouldn't `&stuff.` remove the period?

Comment: @GamrCorps I should specify: Only a single trailing period is consumed in resolution.

Comment: @GamrCorps Edited to specify and added it as a test case.

Comment: so `&&&&&&&&&a......................` would still only remove one period?

Comment: @GamrCorps Yes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>354</s> <s>341</s> 336 bytes

```python
import re
S=re.sub
def f(x):
	r=x.splitlines();C=r[-1].strip('%put ');D=0
	while D!=C:
		D=C
		for a in sorted([l.strip('%let ').replace(" ","").split(';')[0].split('=')for l in r[:-1]],key=lambda y:-len(y[0])):
			s=1
			while s:C,s=re.subn('&'+a[0]+'(\.?)',a[1]+'\\1',S('+\.([^\.])','\\1',C),0,re.I)
	return S('+\.?','',C)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLjpswFF3DV3gsFdsNsYIqTSWQFbUw1XSTLkhWkEakmMYqAWRDJ1G/ofvu@ov9g/SaYdJOpVry4557zrnXhu7cH9rm1eWijl2re6SlmwotuRn2bikrVNETC11HixM3Xa36WjXSUBbFQmfzYMtNr1VHyYtu6BFhUSIWrvNwULVEyY2IQekkIoa1ajUqkGqQgSqypFl9ldbSSrmWXV18khQj7GPMHstREhGWLbZPkSDMOtXWSWchdLD1v8izqIvjvizQOZzXsqFnUDDbtuMYEdjtsSUTxr6ZbtdQ4pFZAcwZoTlfMuIXWQDBr58/vud5QPyUjudZzmn2MedbYJAxETN/4YPLewYPI/tBN@gPdwksS7kYgwTKMMbjBcuhlML0Q1VF7giMZ7G/K1YGEPt8npcAifMINL77JNztbsHndrebWBB7MJ@TlAgm28OHPkjazyB5u1mlV@f7du0pbhOFlugdpDx1g9lzlxOovr0k4Xr9upyU6ZsUKYMepNLlP419LXSAEEjQ/XE5VbdYAJDdJ2iz2qR3CWDXXkYSt8Mabl37Qc34a5jQBUfUadX0tKKGsb9iPP/vwMzSLr8B)

edit: some easy shortening

edit: reverse sort by -len(...) instead of [::-1] (5 bytes), thanks to Jonathan Frech!

### Ungolfed

```python
import re
S=re.sub # new name for the function re.sub()
def f(x):
    r=x.splitlines() # input string to list of rows
    C=r[-1].strip('%put ') # get the string to put (from the last row)
    D=0
    while(D!=C): # iterate until the result does not change
        D=C
        for a in                                                                                                                    : # iterate over the list of variables
                 sorted(                                                                          ,key=lambda y:len(y[0]),reverse=1) # sort list for greediness by decreasing var.name lengths
                        [l.strip('%let ') # cut the 'let' keyword
                                         .replace(" ","") # erase spaces
                                                         .split(';')[0] # cut parts after ';'
                                                                       .split('=') # create [variable_name,value] list
                                                                                  for l in r[:-1]] # for each row but last
            s=1
            while(s): # iterate until the result does not change
                C,s=re.subn( # substitute
                            '&'+a[0]+'(\.?)', # &varname. or &varname
                                                 a[1]+'\\1', # to value. or value
                                                              S('+\.([^\.])','\\1',C), # in the string we can get from C erasing ('s)(.) sequences if the next char is not .
                                                                                        0,re.I) # substituting is case insensitive
    return S('+\.?','',C) # erase smileys and one .
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a lot at the [Python tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python). Trivial optimizations such as non-compound statement concatenation (`;`), parentheses reduction (`if(...)` -> `if ...`) and list operations (`,reverse=1` -> `[::-1]`) can easily save some bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I have read it before, but it was a long time ago, and I forgot some tricks.

Comment: You are welcome. `len(y[0]))[::-1]` can be `-len(y[0]))`.